# iPhone - prevent Invalid Hex character error with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I am parsing an XML coming from a web server and the parsing sometimes stops with Error code 6. From the documentation, I found out the error is NSXMLParserInvalidHexCharacterRefError.

The character in question is Ĵ. Can someone please tell me how I can prevent NSXMLParser from sending an error if it encounters these characters (or rather, doesn't NSXMLParser support unicode encoding?)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I've build a quick test app with the xml <?xml version="1.0" ?><test>Ĵ</test> and it parses fine :( Could you provide some test xml that causes the error? (PS I'm working with a local file, not remote data - it might be a encoding issue inside your app - is your webserver sending the correct encoding headers?)

Comment: I have used the NSXMLParser in the past with several not so common characters and all went fine, I think the encoding was Unicode. You're issue is probably as deanWombourne mentioned related to encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across a similar issue a little while back, I can't seem to find the documentation right now, but I believe that NSXMLParser will evaluate found characters using whatever encoding is specified by the XML document, if the document has characters that are not supported by that encoding the error will occur.

Could you post a sample XML document so we might see what encoding(if any is specified). Also, could you let us know which element the error occurs on?

Comment: Ok. found the issue, thanks to jesse. The XML was not correct. Thanks everyone.